# How does the money a client pays for a therapist affect the effectiveness of the treatment?

Tags: incentives

Do patients who pay more money for a therapy session get more results because they are more committed to the process?

Are there studies that investigated this effect that hold the skill of the therapist constant?

Comment: I do not know if such a study is possible, there is a correlation between expensive and skill. And even if you keep the same therapist with different prices, the therapist can be affected by the money.    But, my opinion is that if you combine the GOOD=EXPENSIVE, the placebo effect and the self-fulfilling prophecy you can conclude that there will be some initial positive effect. This effect though will diminish very quickly if the therapist is not really very skilled.

Comment: @DesignerAnalyst The therapist doesn't have to know about the money. Indeed the theory of the placebo effect would let us expect that there such an effect. If the effect exists that would matter for a lot of policy decisions about how to design the medical system.

Comment: I don't think that paying more will necessarily give you a higher skilled therapist.  The analogy that you get what you pay for is repeated by many people I know and to me that is sometimes found to be a fallacy. Interesting question though which I hope to be able to find an answer to. Especially with the "more commitment" aspect.